# How do I add a custom soap header to a Soap.InvokeRegistry.TRemotable object in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-xe7

I have a large unit generated from a wdsl file which fails to expose the soap header for parameterization. I need to place a custom soap header in the TRemotable query.

```
gepirRequestHeader = class(TSOAPHeader)
  private
    FrequesterGln: string;
    FrequesterGln_Specified: boolean;
    Fcascade: Integer;
    Fcascade_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetrequesterGln(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  requesterGln_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcascade(Index: Integer; const AInteger: Integer);
    function  cascade_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property requesterGln: string   Index (IS_OPTN) read FrequesterGln write SetrequesterGln stored requesterGln_Specified;
    property cascade:      Integer  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcascade write Setcascade stored cascade_Specified;
  end;
```

I need to somehow inject this into objects like this one

```
  GetOwnerOfGLN = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fversion: TXSDecimal;
    Fversion_Specified: boolean;
    FrequestedGln: ArrayOfString;
    FrequestedGln_Specified: boolean;
    FrequestedLanguages: ArrayOfLanguage;
    FrequestedLanguages_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setversion(Index: Integer; const ATXSDecimal: TXSDecimal);
    function  version_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetrequestedGln(Index: Integer; const AArrayOfString: ArrayOfString);
    function  requestedGln_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetrequestedLanguages(Index: Integer; const AArrayOfLanguage: ArrayOfLanguage);
    function  requestedLanguages_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property version:            TXSDecimal       Index (IS_ATTR or IS_OPTN) read Fversion write Setversion stored version_Specified;
    property requestedGln:       ArrayOfString    Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD) read FrequestedGln write SetrequestedGln stored requestedGln_Specified;
    property requestedLanguages: ArrayOfLanguage  Index (IS_OPTN) read FrequestedLanguages write SetrequestedLanguages stored requestedLanguages_Specified;
  end;
```

I know it is theoretically possible to do it by massaging the xml in ObjectToSoap, but is it possible to do it cleanly through with the available objects? If so, how?

Comment: For examples on the desired soap XML, see:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117922&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not string manipulation, and it looks like shite, but it works.
There must be a cleaner way to do this!?

Instead of having the query soap classes inherit from TRemotable, I made a TGepirQuery that adds

```
TGepirQuery = class(TRemotable)
  private
    class var Fcascades: Integer;
    class var FGLN: String;
    var
    FRequestHeader: gepirRequestHeader;
    class procedure Setcascades(const Value: Integer); static;
    class procedure SetGLN(const Value: String); static;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    class constructor CreateTGepirResponse;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function   ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode;
                            const ObjConverter: IObjConverter;
                            const NodeName, NodeNamespace, ChildNamespace: InvString; ObjConvOpts: TObjectConvertOptions;
                            out RefID: InvString): IXMLNode; override;
    class property GLN:String read FGLN write SetGLN;
    class property cascades: Integer read Fcascades write Setcascades;
    property RequestHeader: gepirRequestHeader read FRequestHeader write FRequestHeader;
  published
  end;
```

The ObjectToSoap override is a bit hairy...

```
function TGepirQuery.ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode; const ObjConverter: IObjConverter; const NodeName,
  NodeNamespace, ChildNamespace: InvString; ObjConvOpts: TObjectConvertOptions; out RefID: InvString): IXMLNode;
var
  SoapHeader: IXMLNode;
begin
  SoapHeader := RootNode.ParentNode.AddChild('SOAP-ENV:Header', 0);
  RequestHeader.ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, SoapHeader, ObjConverter, RequestHeader.ClassName, '', '',
    [ocoDontPrefixNode, ocoDontPutTypeAttr], RefID);
  Result := inherited ObjectToSoap(RootNode, ParentNode, objConverter, NodeName, NodeNameSpace, ChildNameSpace, ObjConvOpts, RefID);
end;
```

and the output is "embellished with" a lot of namespace crap that strictly doesn't need to be there.

My result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <NS1:gepirRequestHeader xmlns:NS1="http://www.gepir.org/">
      <requesterGln xmlns="http://www.gepir.org/">7080000366668</requesterGln>
      <cascade xmlns="http://www.gepir.org/">9</cascade>
    </NS1:gepirRequestHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <GetItemByGTIN xmlns="http://www.gepir.org/">
      <requestedGtin>07037211110016</requestedGtin>
    </GetItemByGTIN>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The preferred form per documentation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <gepirRequestHeader xmlns="http://www.gepir.org/">
      <requesterGln>string</requesterGln>
      <cascade>int</cascade>
    </gepirRequestHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetItemByGTIN version="decimal" xmlns="http://www.gepir.org/">
      <requestedGtin>string</requestedGtin>
      <requestedLanguages>
        <language>language</language>
        <language>language</language>
      </requestedLanguages>
    </GetItemByGTIN>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```